# C# Implicit conversion + Unboxing + Conditional expression

Tags: c#, wpf, implicit-conversion

I have a String to Brush converter that I use in WPF to color Listbox items based on text content.

However, as you may already know, the listbox behaves buggy when more string items with the same text are inside and you begin clicking casually you can get more selected items (visually).

To solve this problem I created a class OutputMessage that I implicitly use as a string, but since implicit conversion creates new instances of OutputMessage for each string it converts now the listbox compares instances and not string values and behaves correctly.

But I left the logging manager put plain strings in there since it always prefixes with the current time and there are no duplicates, so the problem would not occur.

But I found a wierd situation with unboxing in the converter:

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            String txt = value is OutputMessage ? (OutputMessage)value : (String)value;
```

By doing this you get:

**Error 1   Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because 'OutputMessage' and 'string' implicitly convert to one another**

We are asigning to a String and there is an implicit conversion in any of the cases, so I tried to use the  conditional expression to choose a 'path' for unboxing the value correctly.

The problem here is that I cannot use

```
String txt = (String)value;
```

or

```
String txt = (OutputMessage)value;
```

because the listbox item could be any of the two, and unboxing the value from object will fail.

I ultimately solved the problem with if statements and type checking, but that kinda kills the usefulness of implicit conversion. I hoped that conditional expressions coudl deal with this :(

Comment: BTW, this has nothing to do with unboxing; that's only for value types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
String txt = value is OutputMessage ? (String)(OutputMessage)value : (String)value;
```

Alternately, you can modify OutputMessage so that one of the conversions is explicit rather than implicit (i.e. allow String to be implicitly converted to OutputMessage, but require OutputMessages to be explicitly converted to String.

Comment: Wow, I never thought of unbox+cast on one side of the conditional. This elegantly solves the problem. THANKS! :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem as you know is that you have two types that are implicitly convertible to each other.

```
String txt = value is OutputMessage ? (OutputMessage)value : (String)value;
```

To execute this statement, the RHS of the assignment gets evaluated first and you end up with an expression that could be interpreted as having a type `OutputMessage` or `String`.  It does not account for what is in the LHS of the statement so this is ambiguous to the compiler.  Remember, the static type of both parts of the conditional must be the same.  You should be explicit about what type you want in this case making both parts of the conditional of type `String` or `OutputMessage`.

```
String txt = value is OutputMessage ? (String)(OutputMessage)value : (String)value;
```

On the other hand, I would rewrite it this way so you're testing the type of the `OutputMessage` (assuming `OutputMessage` is a reference type):

```
var temp = value as OutputMessage;
String txt = temp != null ? (String)temp : (String)value;
```

Comment: I gave a like to you both, but since Dan answered first I accepted his answer. Thanks!

Comment: var temp = value as OutputMessage; will fail is it has a string inside, unboxing wont work :/

Comment: @Marino: Is `OutputMessage` a value type?  If that was the case, then this definitely wouldn't work.  Note that boxing only applies to value types, otherwise it is considered type casting.